# "I would've been" or "I should've been"

Tags: grammar, speech

When on a job interview and asked:

> Tell us more about yourself.

How do I say something like:

> ...Well, **I would've been** a father but sadly my son died due to cord constriction...

My son died on the 35th week of pregnancy, just a few days shy of the due date.

Comment: My deepest sympathy for your tragic loss. But, speaking for myself, I would not mention this extremely sad and personal tragedy in a job interview.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you. I agree, though, my wife was the one just asking me about this and I didn't know how to answer her so I asked here. I'll tell her the same thing. Again, Thank you.

Comment: I think that would be for the best. Once again, my deepest condolences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, condolences on your loss.

The distinction between **should have** and **would have** is small but definite.

**Should have** generally refers to a piece of advice, or something that was supposed to happen but did not against expectation (in a negative sense).

> You ***should have*** listened to me. Then you wouldn't have fallen down.
>
> My arm ***should have*** healed by now, but it still hurts.

**Would have** generally refers to something that might have happened, but didn't due to a specific reason.

> My arm ***would have*** healed, but I didn't take my medicine.

Comment: Accepting this as it is short and clear. Thank you.

Comment: @majidarif Glad to be of some small help

Answer (score 1):

They are both ok, and both give the same main idea: A sad event prevented you from becoming a father.

"I would've been..." gives the meaning that if the accident had not happened, you would have had a child.

"I should've been..." gives the same meaning but also gives the idea that someone or something (for example, "God", the Universe, or you yourself" intended for you to be a father, or that you were supposeThey are both ok, and both give the same main idea: A sad event prevented you from becoming a father.

"I would've been..." gives the meaning that if the accident had not happened, you would have had a child.

"I should've been..." gives the same meaning but also gives the idea that someone or something (for example "God", "the Universe", or you yourself) intended for you to be a father, or that you were supposed to be a father.

For most listeners, the idea that you should have been a father would naturally be included no matter which way you said it.

We can make the second part of the sentence more conventional. Perhaps: "I would've/should've been a father, butd to be a father.

For most listeners, the idea that you should have been a father would naturally be included no matter which way you said it.

We can make the second part of the sentence more conventional. Perhaps: "I would've/should've been a father, but my (our) child died due to a cord constriction." If you wanted to, you could add more information like "died before birth due to..." or "died during pregnancy due to...."